# Separar elementos por categoria

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema en una consulta `sql` de `Mysql`, tengo tres tablas `"categoria"`, `"documento_Identificacion"` y `"categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion"` y su estructura es la siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los valores que tengo por tabla, pero podría registrar más.
**"Tabla categoría"**

```
codigo_categ  |  nombre_categ
-----------------------------------
1             |  Trabajador
2             |  Pensionista
3             |  Prestador de servicios
```

**"tabla documento_Identificacion"**

```
codigo_docIdent  |  nombre_docIdent
---------------------------------------
01               |  Dni
04               |  Carnet de extranjeria
07               |  Pasaporte
```

**"tabla categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion"**, esta tabla contiene datos de las otras dos.

```
codigo_docIdent    |  nombre_docIdent
-----------------------------------------
01  (Dni)          |  1  (Trabajador)
01  (Dni)          |  3  (Prestador de servicios)
04  (Carnet ext.)  |  1  (Trabajador)
04  (Carnet ext.)  |  2  (Pensionista)
07  (Pasaporte)    |  2  (Pensionista)
```

Pero en esta última tabla que se visualiza quiero obtener una `consulta Sql` como se muestra a continuación, el cual tiene que ser de la misma tabla **categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion**:

```
codigo_docIdent    |  Trabajador        |  Pensionista    |  Prestador_de_serv
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01  (Dni)          |  1  (Trabajador)   |  null           |  3 (prestad.)
04  (Carnet ext.)  |  1  (Trabajador)   |  2 (Pensionis.) |  null
07  (Pasaporte)    |  null              |  2 (Pensionis.) |  null
```

Intente hacer este código

```
select d.nombre_docIdent, c.nombre_categ as trabajador, c2.nombre_categ as 
pensionista, c3.nombre_categ as prestador
from categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion as cd
left join documento_Identificacion as d on d.codigo_docIdent = 
cd.codigo_docIdent
left join categoria as c on c.codigo_categ = cd.codigo_categ
left join categoria as c2 on c2.codigo_categ = cd.codigo_categ
left join categoria as c3 on c3.codigo_categ = cd.codigo_categ
where c.codigo_categ = '1' and c2.codigo_categ = '2' and c3.codigo_categ = '3'
order by cd.codigo_docIdent asc;
```

pero no me arroja nada, entonces no se si es posible hacer esto, necesito ayuda nose que funciones debo usar para obtener la consulta que quiero.
**Cualquier solución ha este problema es bienvenida.**

Comment: Eso que queres construir, **parece** una tabla pivotante, pero no entiendo la logica de la tabla que queres construir. no tiene ningun sentido. Podrias explicar la logica para construir esa tabla?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi en la columna `trabajador`, `pensionista` y `prestador` tienen los mismos valores que en su columna, pero esto es solo para visualizar como **administrador** que `categorías de trabajadores` pueden usar tal `documentos`. Pero estoy en eso y no se si el `inner join` basta para esta consulta en la misma tabla.

Comment: Para visualizar donde?

Comment: en una programación o en `consulta` de `Mysql`.

Comment: que quiere decir en una programacion? sigo sin entender el sentido.. no tiene logica.. si la tabla tuviera 100 registros tendrias sin columnas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno amigos ya resolví el problema, pero creo que el código se podría reducir más al que voy a mostrar.
**Primero usamos este código para mostrar solo a los trabajadores.**

```
select codigo_docIdent, c.nombre_categ as trabajador
from categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion as cd
    left join categoria as c on c.codigo_categ = cd.codigo_categ
where c.codigo_categ = '1'
group by codigo_docIdent
```

**Segundo usamos este código para mostrar solo a los pensionistas**

```
select codigo_docIdent, c.nombre_categ as pensionista
from categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion as cd
    left join categoria as c on c.codigo_categ = cd.codigo_categ
where c.codigo_categ = '2'
group by codigo_docIdent
```

**Tercero usamos el siguiente código para mostrar solo a los prestadores de servicios.**

```
select codigo_docIdent, c.nombre_categ as prestador_servicios
from categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion as cd
    left join categoria as c on c.codigo_categ = cd.codigo_categ
where c.codigo_categ = '3'
group by codigo_docIdent
```

Como todos ya están agrupados por sus `códigos`, entonces los unimos de esta manera en la tabla `"categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion"` mostrando en columnas separadas los resultados de cada uno.

```
select cd.codigo_docIdent, doc.nombre_docIdent, categ1.trabajador as 
    trabajador, catg2.pensionista as pensionista,
    catg3.prestador_servicios as prestador_servicios
from categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion as cd
    left join documento_Identificacion as doc on doc.codigo_docIdent = 
        cd.codigo_docIdent
    left join(
        select codigo_docIdent, c.nombre_categ as trabajador
        from categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion as cd
            left join categoria as c on c.codigo_categ = cd.codigo_categ
        where c.codigo_categ = '1'
        group by codigo_docIdent
    ) categ1 on categ1.codigo_docIdent = cd.codigo_docIdent
    left join (
        select codigo_docIdent, c.nombre_categ as pensionista
        from categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion as cd
            left join categoria as c on c.codigo_categ = cd.codigo_categ
        where c.codigo_categ = '2'
        group by codigo_docIdent
        ) catg2 on catg2.codigo_docIdent = cd.codigo_docIdent
    left join (
        select codigo_docIdent, c.nombre_categ as prestador_servicios
        from categoria_y_Documento_Identificacion as cd
            left join categoria as c on c.codigo_categ = cd.codigo_categ
        where c.codigo_categ = '3'
        group by codigo_docIdent
        ) catg3 on catg3.codigo_docIdent = cd.codigo_docIdent
group by doc.nombre_docIdent
order by doc.codigo_docIdent asc;
```

**Bueno eso es todo y el resultado sale como se esperaba.**

Comment: no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada